# Add ImageView in RelativeLayout with coordinates

Tags: android, android-imageview

How to add `ImageView` in `RelativeLayout` with some coordinates, which is bigger than `RelativeLayout` Size?

Trouble is, when I add `ImageView` with padding left bigger then layout width, and use in that layout `scrollTo(-100,0)` (for example), I can't see nothing, my `ImageView` disappeared, or be smaller(when padding left a little less than layout width).

How can I turn off ImageView auto-scaling or something?

Comment: Found one solution: 
android:layout_marginBottom="99999px"(Specifies extra space on the bottom side of this view.)
But this is a hardcode! Why I cant't set somthing like android:layout_marginRight="auto"?